# Is there any way to tell if a program was invoked via CPI in a transaction?

Tags: transactions, cpi

When looking at a transaction, can you tell if a set of inner instructions was invoked by CPI? And then identify that instruction that was called?

eg. [txn](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/34vCJMUFBoy2Tko6YdTt395RhmCrTndEP6kq91MYRcEoNCWjdn56DcMmupUjemo7SBALrfE7sF6KAzvKw9BPdS6T) calls SwapInstruction::Swap, but all we see are TokenProgram::Transfer, TokenProgram::MintTo, and TokenProgram::Transfer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `solana_program::sysvar::instructions::get_instruction_relative`

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/58d10c46e66ca9d9c6288999ca9289c986587c7f/candy-machine/program/src/processor/mint.rs#L115

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/58d10c46e66ca9d9c6288999ca9289c986587c7f/candy-machine/program/src/processor/mint.rs#L151-L164

Comment: This would tell me who is making the CPI, but not what the source instruction is, right? In the example I linked, I want to know that SwapInstruction::Swap is the actual instruction invoked, creating the subsequent TokenProgram::Transfer, TokenProgram::MintTo, and TokenProgram::Transfer inner instructions

Comment: let current_ix = get_instruction_relative(0, &instruction_sysvar_account_info).unwrap();

If current_ix.program_id == swap_program.program_id then this instruction is the actual instruction invoked, except this instruction is called by it's program itself via cpi.

Comment: If current_ix.program_id != swap_program.program_id then this instruction is called via cpi by another program.